# Laravel 6 - How to make user cannot use tomorrow and later date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to make user wouldn't be able to pick date after today, so they will only be able to input today's date or before that.

This is my calendar code I'm using `carbon`

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('transaction_in_date', 'Transaction Date') }} <br>
    {{ Form::date('transaction_in_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d M Y')) }}
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: try `{{ Form::date('transaction_in_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d M Y'), ['max' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d M Y') ]) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [before or equal](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-before-or-equal) validation rule:

```
'transaction_in_date' => 'before_or_equal:today'
```

Comment: How do i put it there exactly?

Comment: You put this in your controller, or the FormRequest, depending on how you do a validation. You can do a client side validation, but you have to add a server side validation as well, because the client side can be bypassed.

Comment: @Aditya and does it work? If it does you can mark the answer as the solution.